# CommandParameter's bound SelectedIndex is returning last selection, or -1

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've implemented MVVM in WPF and have a `ListView` as follows:

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="ListViewMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

... GridView in ListView.View ...

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSelectionChangedCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex, 
                                       ElementName=ListViewMain}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Whenever I change selection by clicking on any item on the `ListView`, `OnSelectionChangedCommand` is called with correct `SelectedIndex`.

But when I change `SelectedIndex` programatically as follows:

```
ListViewMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I get -1 in `OnSelectionChangedCommand`. How do I get correct `SelectedIndex` irrespective of selection change method?

**Update**

The answers in [WPF Listview SelectionChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367665/wpf-listview-selectionchanged-event) don't explain what'll happen when `SelectedIndex` is set programmatically and how to define the view model's property which is bound do `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: Why are you doing all this, instead of just binding the SelectedIndex or SelectedItem property?

Comment: @Clemens: I need the index to access the model data around selected index. Like if selected index is 10, I need to access 11 etc.

Comment: Then just add a property to your view model that holds the selected index.

Comment: Why are you typing TableTestCaseView.ListViewMain.SelectedIndex instead of only ListViewMain.SelectedIndex?

Comment: @Clemens: My problem is I need to programmatically change current selection, where I have only the index which I'd like to be selected.

Comment: @WasifMahmoodMustafa: Because `ListViewMain` is embedded in `TableTestCaseView` in the program I'm writing.

Comment: @WasifMahmoodMustafa: I've understood your confusion and removed extra code. Thanks.

Comment: "*I need to programmatically change current selection, where I have only the index which I'd like to be selected*" - that is exactly what happens when you bind SelectedIndex.

Comment: Can you post more code? Like where are you initializing the selectedindex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Listview SelectionChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367665/wpf-listview-selectionchanged-event)

Comment: @Clemens: Can you please explain why binding `SelectedIndex` to a property in the view model will achieve what I need?

Comment: @Clemens: Never mind. I figured it out finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got the solution. The `ListView` should bind `SelectedIndex` with a property in view model:

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="ListViewMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
```

The `ListView` shouldn't trigger on `SelectionChanged` event.

The `ListView.DataContext.SelectedIndex` (the view model's `SelectedIndex`) property should call `SelectionChanged` handler:

```
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get => _selected_index;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selected_index, value);
        OnSelectionChangedCommand.Execute(_selected_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you probably don't need a command anymore. Just call the command's Execute handler directly from the property setter.

Comment: Yep. That's true, that's next part. :)